# Check data is same for one or more records using T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having 2 tables with a relation of one to many

For example take example of student and performance tables. Here a student and performance tables have one to many relationship

**Student:**
[image]

**Performance:**
[image]

Now i have to write a stored procedure which takes input as multiple student id, student name and section details as datatable and tells whether all the records passed in datatable have the same values for percentage, subject id, other activities in performance table or not .

Any suggestions are helpful

Comment: Prepare for feedback on the terrible design of the tables.  The `Student` table is completely pointless since you include ALL of that data in your `Performance` table.  You really should be normalizing this.

Comment: Its an example i provided to relate my business scenario

Comment: @Sandeep - do your real tables have similar duplication?

Comment: Yes my DB is in denormalized state, as it supports my requirement

Comment: @Sandeep - if it's denormalized to THIS DEGREE than it's poor design, no matter what the requirement

Comment: Noo, in my tables i can identify records uniquely using 3 columns so those columns will be repeated across tables, and the sources for these values are external which i pull data using SSIS

Comment: Then is there a table that just has those 3 columns in it?  Because that table is a waste of drive space.

Comment: No it has lot of columns other than those mentioned here as example

Comment: @Sandeep - I was just referring to the fact that the `Student` table had no data not present in `Performance`

Comment: Not to be too rude, but since you completely changed the requirement I'm done trying to help here.  good luck!

Comment: Sorry JNK, i edited my problem description to properly convey my requirement

Comment: I can see that when `Subject Id` is empty, `Other Activities` is not, and vice versa. 1. Is that always so? 2. What type is `Subject Id` (I mean, if it is not `int`). On another point (question #3), is `Student` that same datatable which contains the student details as parameters?

Comment: 1. Yes, always it contains data in that way 2. NVARCHAR 3. Yes

Comment: Can you please post the 'real life' example?

Comment: Posting that creates lot of confusion as its related to some POs IOs  of SAP Data :( . But i tried my best in providing the student example as it just replica of my problem, u can consider student table as datatable which i am passing as parameter and see all records in datatable have the same data in performance table or not

Comment: Hello, can anyone help me on this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns no rows if all the students queried have got identical data:

```
WITH StudentCount AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM Students
),
RowDataCounts AS (
  SELECT
    p.Percentage,
    p.SubjectId,
    p.OtherActivities,
    Cnt = COUNT(*)
  FROM Performance p
    INNER JOIN Student s
       ON p.StudentID = s.StudentID
      AND p.Name = s.Name
      AND p.Section = s.Section
  GROUP BY
    p.Percentage,
    p.SubjectId,
    p.OtherActivities
)
SELECT r.*
FROM RowDataCounts r
  LEFT JOIN StudentCounts s ON r.Cnt = s.Cnt
WHERE s.Cnt IS NULL
```

If not all the data are identical across all the students, the query will return rows showing the actual pieces of data that aren't the same, as well as how many students have that information.

If you need to use the entire query in a condition like `IF EXISTS (…)`, just transform the CTEs to conventional subselects, i.e. like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM ( … /* the RowDataCounts subquery here */ ) r
  INNER JOIN ( … /* the StudentCount subquery here */ ) s ON r.Cnt = s.Cnt
WHERE s.Cnt IS NULL
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a simplified version of the same solution:

```
SELECT
  p.Percentage,
  p.SubjectId,
  p.OtherActivities,
  Cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM Performance p
  INNER JOIN Student s
     ON p.StudentID = s.StudentID
    AND p.Name = s.Name
    AND p.Section = s.Section
GROUP BY
  p.Percentage,
  p.SubjectId,
  p.OtherActivities
HAVING COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students)
```

Comment: @Sandeep: Updated my answer with a simpler version.